# Mapping to entity id with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Is there a way to map entities by their ID?

Currently i have a code that works liek this:

User object has some roles assigned to it:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLES", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
protected List<Role> assignedRoles = new ArrayList<>();
```

Role is mapped to users:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "assignedRoles")
protected Collection<? extends User> users;
```

The thing is, what i want is something like:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "assignedRoles")
protected Collection<Integer> users;
```

To operate userIds instead of User objects.

Is it possible to somehow configure Mapping to work this way? I failed to find anything on this in available Hibernate documentation.

Comment: Why do you want to have integers instead of user objects? I assume your user object is not very complex, so it is almost equal whether you query the primary keys only or the entire user row. You can get the id later from the user objects.

Comment: Since Integer is not an entity, you can't do this. I can see 2 options. The first is to still use a User entity, with a single ID. The second is to remove the many-to-many relation, and consider using the USER_ID column of the ROLE table directly.

Comment: @isnot2bad while not very complex (all the business logic is moved to a mutable class derived from the immutable one), User is mapped to Groups, Roles and several other entities, which are all mapped to each other and sometimes even to themselves.
However, biggest concern here is the amount of refactoring required across the product, since we are moving to hibernate from in-house ORM which used mapping by primary keys.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the solution provided by tringel, you could also try to use hibernate's basic collection mapping feature:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="USER_ROLES", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID"))
@Column(name="USER_ID")
protected Set<Integer> users;
```

With this strategy you could also map more complex value types like some sort of `UserRef` object that contains the user id and some other useful properties:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="USER_ROLES", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID"))
@Column(name="USER_ID")
protected Set<UserRef> users;

...
@Embeddable
public class UserRef {
    public Integer id;
    public String name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the addition. I found out that i have to use `@ElementCollection` anyway, otherwise Hibernate won't recognise the List type. I will do my research on `@CollectionTable` as it seems to be useful for our case where we want to cache only some parts of the entity.

Comment: Very interesting, in this case this seems to fit even better.

Comment: @DmitryKorchemkin Please be aware that this is a value-type-mapping and bad things may happen if you modify the role's user list as Hibernate assumes a owner-relationship between roles and users. Removing a user-id from the list might delete the entire user row!

Comment: @isnot2bad thx, i'll be sure to test this before moving forward with implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using Hibernates @Formula instead of a mapping.
So for your user_roles table with columns user_id and role_id, this should work:

```
@Formula("(SELECT USER_ID " +
        "FROM USER_ROLES " +
        "WHERE ROLE_ID = id")
protected Collection<Integer> users;
```

In this example the parameter *id* is the id field from the entity using this formula, so probably the role entity.
If your user entity is a fairly basic entity this would probably not improve performance (as isnot2bad already mentioned). We used it instead of fetching a very complex entity with several relationships, where it can improve performance considerably.

Comment: We have entities that probably would qualify as "complex", user is related to groups, roles, authenticators, etc. Each of those entities is mapped to several others and sometimes even to itself (group can be a part of other group).